# How complex can a Hadoop Map Reduce program be?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing, bigdata

Two basic general questions, I hope you can clarify:

- Does every program executed via Hadoop has to be written in the Map/Reduce format?
- How complex can those programs be? (Is it theoretically possible to run any program via Hadoop?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first question:yes
because Hadoop uses map/reduce model,but you can use only map function in some problem,for example sorting!

your second question:no
hadoop can not do everything,because it use map/reduce model,some program can not be resolved to map/reduce,like Nested program,so some companies developed many other program models just like pregel, dremel and so on!